# what are the default permissions of linux server var folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, server, var

Unknowingly I give 777 permissions for var folder (chmod -R 0777 /var/).So all the sites in that server are now not coming.I am getting this error,

This site can’t be reached

www.domainname.com refused to connect.

How to revert var folder permissions to default.

Please can you help me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Since Each process has its own mask, which is applied whenever the process creates a new file.
you can check the mask using command
**umask**
it will show by default ***022*** 
later it will subtract the above value **777-022=755** 
so now the file has permission like **-**rwx-r-x-r-x****

so it depends on what is the value of umask so please check the umask value and according to that set the value of var

or,
you can set the var directory folder as

**drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Dec 21 19:59 var**

command :-or use command

***chmod 755 var***